# How to install Mono 4.0

Tags: apt, ppa, mono

I want to use Mono on VSCode, so I installed Mono 3.2.8 but VSCode told me I need Mono 3.10 or higher so I decide to just install Mono 4 but I just can't. I uninstalled Mono-Complete, added PPA for mono latest and reinstall but I still got 3.2.8 instead of Mono 4, what did I do wrong?

Comment: your ubuntu version is?